# I made my hard drive bootable using rufus and cannot turn it back as non bootable hard drive

Tags: hard-drive

I have 2 disks one with `linux 500gb` and one with `windows 256gb`, both are bootable so I choose OS when starting computer. I want to stay on windows and use second hard drive (where linux installed now) as USB devise from windows so I should format it somehow. How could I do that?

PS I made 500gb hard drive bootable using rufus, I cannot  format hard drive with linux while I am using it, but I do not see such ssd in my computer to click format

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

1. Boot into windows
2. Open disk management
3. You should see your disks listed below. Try formatting the desired drive.

Comment: I can only create new Tom, transform it as dynamic disk or GPT disk. When I had tom of disk format button was not clickable. I made it as bootable, I think that is the reason becaue it was working fine before

Comment: While I try to create new tom it offers me to format disk, I tried it will se if it works

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to create new Tom & it will format it automatically and it will be able to be shown as E (or whatever I want it be named) disk

Answer (score 0):

> I want to stay on windows and use second hard drive (where linux
> installed now) as USB devise from windows so I should format it
> somehow.
> So I assume you are talking about a portable hard drive.

If I didn't get you wrong, I understand the question you are asking is "Why cannot I see the portable hard drive (currently bootable with Linux) as a USB device when I connect it to the PC and I am on Windows?".

This is not a solution but a hint for what might be happening: when there's a dual boot with Windows and Linux, you can access Windows file system from Linux but you can't access Linux file system from Windows. I think it has to do with the fact that Linux is always installed after Windows.

Comment: Yes, you got it right, I can see it from linux and cannot from windows. I wrote my solution below, do not know why it worked for me but everything fine now